# How to convert ZZ to binary?

Tags: c, ntl

I'm using the NTL library to implement my code and I have to ZZ number which I have to convert to binary then take a substring from it and convert that substring into decimal. How can I do that?

```
ZZ N;
unsigned char pp[200];
BytesFromZZ(pp,N,NumBits(N));
```

The above code is giving me this error: "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"

EDIT : Above code is working now but instead of giving octal string it is returning garbage values.

Comment: BytesfromZZ but it is not working. I am looking for something inbuild.

Comment: I dont understand why people are downvoting instead of giving solution.

Comment: Because you've shown no code. Show us what you have and where it is failing and we may be able to help.

Comment: I have edited the question and added the code lines. Sorry but it is not formatting as code even after using 4 blanks.

Comment: At a glance, you typically want to allocate a buffer before trying to fill it.

Comment: Can you please explain?

Comment: AFAICT from [this page](http://www.shoup.net/ntl/doc/ZZ.txt), `BytesFromZZ` returns raw bytes, not an octal string. I also note that you're using `NumBits()` instead of `NumBytes()`, which is probably wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You should use NumBytes, and a result is a reversed string.

Answer (score 1):

The array `pp` which holds the byte-representation of `N` must be allocated with size equal to `NumBytes(N)`. Otherwise, you get a SegFault if the length of `pp` is less than `NumBytes(N)`.
In addition, probably because of the Little-Endianess of Intel CPUs, `pp` represents `N` as a byte-string in reversed order.

```
ZZ N;
// assigning whatever value to N
unsigned char* pp = new unsigned char[NumBytes(N)];
BytesFromZZ(pp, N, NumBytes(N)); // pp = byte-representation of N
delete[] pp;
```